# How to execute a set of async tasks in nodejs in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to perform a set of async tasks repeatedly in a loop. I tried using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library's **waterfall** approach to do something like

```
while(somethingIsTrue) {
     async.waterfall([
         function(callback) { ... },
         function(callback) { ... },

     ], function(err) {
         ...
        }
     );
}
```

The problem I encountered was that the the first async function never got scheduled or rather executed and the loop kept on running, obviously because the loop didnt wait for the async functions to finish. I'm not so well verse with asynchronous programming and I would need help to come up with some pattern to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try a semi-recursive solution such as

```
function again_and_again(callback) {
    if (!somethingIsTrue) return;
    async.waterfall([
         function(callback) { ... },
         function(callback) { ... },
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        again_and_again(callback);
    });
}
```

The idea is to wait for the waterfall to finish, and arrive at the callback, and repeat the "loop" there by calling `again_and_again` again.

Comment: Alternatively, [`async#whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback) might also be useful.